# What parts of math are concerned with computing the order of points on a cubic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, big-list

On p. 123 of *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach*, it says that

> Many areas of mathematics are concerned with the computation of the order of various points on a cubic curve.

What are some examples of this?

I am not familiar with any examples from my previous studies. The text refers obliquely to applications to number theory at times, which might explain this discrepancy -- I know next to nothing of number theory. Still, it seems from the above that there should also be applications outside of number theory, whereas I am not aware of any yet.

Comment: This is a good question, and I will be interested to see the answers. It's easy to make sweeping statements about the importance of your subject matter when your readers can't press you for details!

Comment: A weaker statement: the more structure a variety has, often the more you can say about it. A lot of (counter)examples in birational geometry start off with "pick an elliptic curve with complex multiplication" and then proceed to exploit the group structure. The more explicit you can be about this the better.