# What is the smooth elliptic curve group and how does it relate to the torus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the following quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), given without citation or reference:

> Using the theory of elliptic functions, it can be shown that elliptic curves defined over the complex numbers correspond to embeddings of the torus into the complex projective plane. The torus is also an abelian group, and in fact this correspondence is also a group isomorphism.

This leads me to have at least the following several questions:

**1.** For each possible value of the $j$-invariant in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$, there is a unique family of projectively equivalent smooth elliptic curves. Does each of these families lead to a different group (up to isomorphism) and thus a different torus?

**2.** What is the group of the torus being referred to, the fundamental group of the torus ($\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$)? That would mean then that there is ***only one*** smooth elliptic curve group up to group isomorphism?

(I guess that would sort of make sense, since each smooth elliptic curve corresponds to a different Weierstrass $\wp$ function, each of which corresponds to a different lattice on $\mathbb{C}$, but the quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ with any lattice $\Lambda$ is still the "same" torus.)

**3.** Is this the simplest way to think about the smooth elliptic curve groups formed by the chord-tangent composition law with respect to the base point at infinity? Does the answer to two explain/justify/correspond to the following quote from the end of section 2.4 of  *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach*?

> In general, there are $n^2$ points on $\mathcal{C}$ [the smooth elliptic curve] whose order divides $n$. Hence, there are twelve points of order four on $\mathcal{C}$, as there will be sixteen whose order divides four, but four of those are already counted among the three points of order two and the identity $O$.

**Note:** this question is a follow-up to at least two of my previous questions:
- [Is this a space filling curve for a torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922370/is-this-a-space-filling-curve-for-a-torus)
- [What parts of math are concerned with computing the order of points on a cubic curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919429/what-parts-of-math-are-concerned-with-computing-the-order-of-points-on-a-cubic-c)

I know that the answers to my questions could probably be easily googled, but I wouldn't know what to search for, and probably would not understand most of the references. The simpler the answer, the better.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid the values $j = 0$ and $j = 1$.  Over the complex numbers, the underlying additive group is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^2/\mathbf Z^2$.  You need to think of elliptic curves over $\mathbf C$ as complex Lie groups, not just as abstract abelian groups, to say that elliptic curves with different $j$-invariants are not isomorphic. As an analogy, consider the rings $\mathbf Z[i]$ and $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{2}]$. As additive groups they are isomorphic to each other (they are both isomorphic to $\mathbf Z^2$), but as rings they are not isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Elliptic curves over $\Bbb C$ have the group structure of a torus, namely, that of $S^1 \times S^1$. So they are all group-isomorphic. Elliptic curves over finite fields however are much more complicated. Different $j$-invariant gives different elliptic curves *upto biholomorphism*. Of course all elliptic curves, being homeomorphic to torus, are homeomorphic to each other so the homeomorphism class is uninteresting.

Comment: Thank you both -- your comments also explain the $n^2$ thing, since the points whose order divides $n$ are just products of roots of unity, there are $n$ $n$th roots of unity in each copy of the circle, thus by the counting principle $n^2$ elements whose order divides $n$ (I am mostly saying this for my own future reference or that of others).